# AS3: How to keep sound from playing if one is already playing?

Tags: actionscript-3

Basically, when a link is clicked in the main.swf, an external swf is loaded. Each swf has a back button, which returns you to the main.swf. The problem is, when the main.swf is brought back, it starts playing the music again overdubbing the original. I've even tried linking back to a version of main.swf that doesn't have the audio code, no luck.

After googling, this code is supposed to check if a sound is playing. It's giving me errors.

[Check if SoundChannel is playing sound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194150/check-if-soundchannel-is-playing-sound)

Thanks!

Comment: The code you're talking about is intended with the flex SDK. 
You need to link to the flex sdk in your fla settings.
this is because of the Embed part.
You may need to change private var s:Song;
with private var s:SoundPlayer_Song;
You can test this in flash by trying this:
var s:*;
s = new Song();
trace(getQualifiedClassName(s));

But please if you get errors, post your code here.

Comment: I just took the easy way out and added SoundMixer.stopAll(); // Stop Sound to prevent overlap