# ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property running not found on flash.media.SoundChannel and there is no default value. - Simple Music "Button"

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, air, audio-player

I have a little music button that when clicked stops a music channel, and when clicked again plays it. It starts of playing and when I click it I get an error:

Here is the full error:

```
ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property running not found on flash.media.SoundChannel and there is no default value.
    at [PROJECTNAME]::MainTimeline/fl_TapHandler_8()[Rockfall_fla.MainTimeline::frame3:215]
    at runtime::ContentPlayer/simulationSendTouchEvent()
    at runtime::SimulatedContentPlayer/clientSocketDataHandler()
```

Frame 3 line 215 refers to this line of code:

```
if(Chn_musicLoop.running == true){
```

The small function that deals with the music looks like this:

```
function fl_TapHandler_8(event:TouchEvent):void
{
    if(Chn_musicLoop.running == true){
    musicIcon.alpha *= 0.5;
    Chn_musicLoop.stop();
    }
    else{
        musicIcon.alpha *= 2;
        Chn_musicLoop.play()
    }}
```

Is there something I'm missing? When I click "`dismiss`" on the text box, it stops the music like it should...

Comment: Chn_musicLoop is SoundChannel?

Comment: yes. It is a sound channel. Here's the code for it: "var musicLoop = new bgMusic();
var Chn_musicLoop = new SoundChannel();"

Comment: But according to documentation, there so 'running' parameter for SoundChannel.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/SoundChannel.html

Comment: So what would I need to do to fix this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194150/check-if-soundchannel-is-playing-sound

Comment: Thanks, this fixed my problem. What would I use to START a soundchannel again? IT seems like there is no soundchannel.play(); only a soundchannel.stop();

Comment: `Sound` does, so you need to do play() on a Sound instance (this is returning SoundChannel).

Comment: Please post the answer as an "answer" below and accept it, even if it is just a summary and a link. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was told to add this as answer:

- Chn_musicLoop is SoundChannel?
- yes.  It is a sound channel. Here's the code for it: "var musicLoop = new bgMusic(); var Chn_musicLoop = new SoundChannel();"
- But according to documentation, there so 'running' parameter for SoundChannel. help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/…